# Can I uninstall Visual Basic from Visual Studio 11 beta?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to *not* install all components of Visual Studio 11 Ultimate? Specifically, having Visual Basic installed makes project selection clumsy. While I am at it, I would also uninstall F# and C++, leaving a simpler environment for C# web development. Does the beta not have this granularity yet?

Comment: How does it make project selection clumsy?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way in the beta to remove languages.

Also if you set your settings in Visual Studio to General Development Settings and VB is listed first in the New Project dialog.  Because the beta has a problem where it doesn't remember your last project type you keep getting VB projects selected when doing C# work.

I'm not sure if this is your problem but if it is you can fix this

- Go to Tools | Import and Export Settings
- Select Import selected environment settings and click Next
- Decide if you want to save your settings and click Next
- Choose Visual C# Development Settings and click Next
- Deselect everything except for the General Settings > New Project Dialog Preferred Language entry and click Finish.

When you add a new project you will have C# as your default.

Hopefully that helps